# nextProps in typescript (functional component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a problem with typescript.
Can you please tell me how to rewrite the useEffect hook from "nextProps" (jsx) to typescript (tsx)?

```
useEffect((nextProps) => {
    if (nextProps.selectedProviderJob !== selectedProviderJob) {
      setState({
        trackingEventOrder: "",
        nextNote: "",
        selectedSubpayers: [],
        approvalDate: null,
        followUpDate: null,
        isApproved: false,
        isPending: false,
        providerNumber: nextProps.selectedProviderJob.providerNumber,
      });
    }
  }, [props]);
```

Comment: what problem do you see?

Comment: `useEffect` callback doesn't receive any arguments. Check the docs `type EffectCallback = () => (void | Destructor);`

Comment: Argument of type '(nextProps: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The useEffect hook does not get any return type, so there is no type to set. In addition to that, using props in the second argument of the useEffect could cause heavy workload and reloading if there are more props passed to the component. So I would not recommend that if you are relying on only one variable.

I have to correct this answer. The useEffect-method **has a return type**. You can pass a method which will run when the component gets destroyed. But that is not needed in your case.

```
useEffect(() => {[function that returns nothing]}, [variables which trigger the hook by change]);
```

Comment: How we will have more props if they are described in the interface ?

Comment: You can pass multiple props to a component, which are all accessible through the props obj. Example: `<Component propsA="this is a" propsB="this is b"/>`. To access propsA and propsB, you have to refer them by props.propsA and props.propsB in the component object. If you pass props to the hook, it will run if props.propsA AND props.propsB changes